# C# (Найти ошибку) Поменять местами первый минимальный и последний максимальный элемент

Tags: c#

> В одномерном массиве поменять местами первый минимальный и последний
>   максимальный элемент.

Есть код, но он срабатывает через раз, не могу понять почему. помогите найти ошибку пожалуйста

```
        Console.WriteLine("******Задание 2******");
        Console.WriteLine("Введите размерность масисва");
        n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        int[] arr2 = new int[n];

        Console.WriteLine("\n\n");
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            arr2[i] = rnd.Next(-20, 30);
            Console.Write($"{arr2[i],4}  ");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();

        int tmp = arr2[Array.LastIndexOf(arr2, arr2.Max())];
        arr2[Array.LastIndexOf(arr2, arr2.Max())] = arr2[Array.IndexOf(arr2, arr2.Min())];
        arr2[Array.IndexOf(arr2, arr2.Min())] = tmp;

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            Console.Write($"{arr2[i],4}  ");
        }


        Console.ReadKey();
        Console.Clear();
```

Comment: Учитесь дебажить, поставьте точку остановки на строку `int tmp =` и пройдите по-шагам дальше наблюдая за значениями переменных, таким образом вы самостоятельно найдете где у вас неправильно. Такой навык так же важен, как и собственно навык написания кода. И это и есть программирование: пишем, запускаем, находим ошибки, запускаем по-шагам, находим где криво, исправляем, снова запускаем...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добрый день. Вся проблема в том, что у вас каждый раз по новой вычисляется индексы максимального и минимального элемента массива. В контексте вашей задачи - это неверно.
Рассмотрим пример [3, 0, -1] ожидаемый результат выполнения вами будет [-1, 0, 3]. Но по вашему коду произойдет следующее:

1. Мы запоминаем максимальное число
2. Заменяем число в индексе max на число в индексе min
3. Заменяем число в индексе min на запомненное ранее число

В 3 пункте и кроется ошибка. У вас после 2-го пункта следующий массив [-1, 0, -1] и вы находите первый индекс минимального и записываете туда максимальное число. А первый индекс минимального - 0. И получается на выходе [3, 0, -1].
Как будто ничего и не поменялось.

Вот исправленный код:

```
Console.WriteLine("******Задание 2******");
Console.WriteLine("Введите размерность масисва");
n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
int[] arr2 = new int[n];

Console.WriteLine("\n\n");
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    arr2[i] = rnd.Next(-20, 30);
    Console.Write($"{arr2[i],4}  ");
}
Console.WriteLine();

int maxIndex = Array.LastIndexOf(arr2, arr2.Max());
int minIndex = Array.IndexOf(arr2, arr2.Min());
int tmp = arr2[maxIndex];
arr2[maxIndex] = arr2[minIndex];
arr2[minIndex] = tmp;

for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    Console.Write($"{arr2[i],4}  ");
}


Console.ReadKey();
Console.Clear();
```

Comment: Спасибо :) А почему иногда срабатывало?

Comment: @dadyaSasha я же объяснил, но на примере, который не работал. Смотрите, если взять в пример [-1, 0, 3], то всё будет работать. Мы запомним число 3 (под индексом 2). Заменим его на -1, получится [-1, 0, -1]. А дальше найдем число -1 (под индексом 0, первое минимальное) и заменим его на tmp и получится [3, 0, -1], как раз, ваш ожидаемый результат :-)

Comment: почему не работало я понял, а почему мой код иногда срабатывал?

Comment: а все, до меня дошло

Comment: @dadyaSasha отлично! :-)
Если что, пишите еще, будем помогать чем можем. Методы Array.IndexOf и Array.LastIndexOf вычисляют каждый раз новый индекс, в уже измененном массиве.