С делать нужно на c#
Ввести целое число N и массив из N вещественных чисел. Поменять
местами первый и минимальный элементы массива

С делайте, мы не против

Сразу выдало в похожих. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/728010/c-%d0%9d%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%bc%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d1%8d?rq=1
